# List full timestamps of files in a tarball

Tags: linux, command-line, tar, metadata, timestamp

I have a large `tar` archive and want to see the **exact** (nanosecond) timestamps that are stored for each file in the archive. In case it's relevant, the tarball is in POSIX-2001 format (`tar --format=posix`).

`tar --list --verbose` displays the timestamps rounded off to the minute.

For comparison, `ls --full-time` does what I want, but I'd rather not have to extract everything first because it's huge.

For my purposes, command-line and GUI tools are both fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I might be misreading your question but have you tried `tar -t -v --full-time -f`?

Comment: I swear I tried that before and it didn't work, but now it does. Strange.